# I am new to coding and just do not understand what this error code means

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have only recently begun coding with Python 3. I don't know how to phrase the question that I mean to ask as I don't understand any part of these errors that were returned.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Liam McAuley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\Liam McAuley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Liam McAuley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Liam McAuley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\shrek.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
  File "C:\Users\Liam McAuley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Liam McAuley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Either your chromedriver.exe is missing or it is installed in a directory that is not in PATH.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. _I don't understand any part of these errors that were returned._ Any part? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

Your system cannot find the chromerdriver executable. As you are using Windows, I'd recommend using a full path definition of the executable:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Users\Liam McAuley\path\to\actual\chromedriver.exe")
```

Alternatively, you can add chromedriver.exe to your path by typing this command into Command Prompt (make sure you are running as administrator!)

```
 setx CHROMEDRIVER=C:\Users\Liam McAuley\path\to\actual\chromedriver.exe
```

Comment: Dude, I feel like I look like a total idiot right now.   When I tried your first suggestion, a pop-up appeared saying --- (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3 truncated \uxxxxxxxx escape --- so I googled and founded on an earlier post about a similar issue which was cleared by putting an r before the directory and that brought up the original error.      As for the second option, i was presented with ---ERROR: Invalid syntax. The default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).--- after entering your suggested command.  Thank you for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the trace it may seem as if there are two things that are going wrong. 1st one is that it seems as if python cannot find the file you are specifying so perhaps check your path. the second one is that you may not have chromedriver on your PATH. if you're using windows you can add it to the path via the environment variables tab. you can also follow the steps found [here](https://developers.refinitiv.com/sites/default/files/How%20To%20Add%20ChromeDriver%20To%20System%20Variables_0.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium tries to access chromdriver which is a Webdriver it uses to execute the

```py
   driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
```

In order to use the chromedriver, it has to be on path. You can get the chromedriver [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). As for how to add stuff to path, you can either use SETX temporarily

```
   setx CHROMEDRIVER=path/to/chromedriver.exe
```

or you can create a folder for the driver and then add that folder permanently to path by following these instructions [here](https://www.techjunkie.com/environment-variables-windows-10/)

Comment: SETX is for permanent modification of the environment variables. Temporary modifications are handled by SET. https://superuser.com/a/916652